# Regex for removing special character from string using angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to create a angular js filter who will remove space with "-" and remove special character like ™ tm , ℠ sm, ® r,© .Below code will remove space with "-" but not remove the special characters

```
 (function (angular) {
    'use strict';
            angular.module('myApp')
            .filter('removespace', function () {
                return function(input) {
                    if(input) {
                        return input.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
                    }
                };
            });

})(angular);


 Output will be

    LG Stylo™ 2 PLUS >> lg-stylo-2-plus
    ZTE AVID® TRIO >> zte-avid-trio
    ZTE ZMAX® Pro >> zte-zmax-pro
    HTC Desire® 530 >> htc-desire-530
    Galaxy S® 6 edge - Gold - 32GB - Cert. Pre-Owned >> galaxy-s-6-edge-gold-32gb-cert-pre-owned
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
return input.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^-\w]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

(`[^-\w]` means "everything except `-` and a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`", i.e. the resulting string will only contain `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, -`.)

Comment: but it is fail if we convert "Galaxy S® 6 edge - Gold - 32GB - Cert. Pre-Owned".it should be 'galaxy-s-6-edge-gold-32gb-cert-pre-owned' instead of 'galaxy-s-6-edge---gold---32gb---cert-pre-owned'

Comment: That's slightly another requirement. Use this:
`input.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^-\w]+/g, '').replace(/-{2,}/g, '-').toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

```
input.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'')
    .replace(/ +/g,'-');
```

Comment: Not working for this, Galaxy S® 6 edge - Gold - 32GB - Cert. Pre-Owned >> galaxy-s-6-edge-gold-32gb-cert-pre-owned @damian

Comment: What about `replace(/\s+/g, '-')` instead of `replace(/ +/g,'-')`?